# Is there a way to make a scrollbar for plots in the matlab app designer?

Tags: matlab, scrollbar, matlab-app-designer

I am building an app with the App Designer. The figure includes multiple plots that are synced. I would like to make something to scroll through the plots so that I can show a set amount of time at any given time. As it is now, it includes the ability to pan and zoom with just mouse controls. I cannot find a way to make such a scroll bar.

I was thinking of using the slider tool to keep re-plotting the plot based on where the slider begins, but that solution is very messy. And it could lead to some data never appearing.

Even if I could just make some way for me to set the plot to just show a given x interval (say 100 units of time) and use a key press to go to the next x interval without skipping anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out the `XLim` and `YLim` properties of the axes. Those you want to control with your sliders.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I was playing around with those, but the issue is that it seems to ignore the xlims after I import the data into the app. The app works by asking for a csv file, which it then grabs data from on the stop and plots. If I set the Xlims before, before introducing the data, the xlims on the graph match. But as soon as the data is imported, it acts as if there were no limits. It just shows the entire plot with its entire x-axis shown

Comment: In MATLAB, when plotting, axes properties are often reset. You need to plot first, then set the xlim.